# C++ socket Connect is stuck when trying to connect to a unreachable computer

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, ip

Source Code:

```
    bool Helper::connectToAComputer(char* destIpString, char* srcIpString)
{
    int iResult = 0;
    u_long iMode = 1;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        //return NULL;
    }

    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(destIpString);
    clientService.sin_port = htons(22223);

    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *)& clientService, sizeof(clientService));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    return false;
}
```

I am writing a program that will check all local IP addresses to see which computers or devices are on the local network. I have written this function which connects to a socket.

The problem is that when the socket tries the connect to an IP that is not owned by any device, the program just stops and waits on the connect line. It can connect to IP's that are owned by a computer. I want the function to tell me whether the connect was not successful instead of just hanging and waiting.

Comment: TCP cannot tell that address is unreachable without waiting for timeout. It is not clear what you want from it.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, thanks for your answer. Then how can I check if a address is reachable or not?

Comment: It is not a trivial task. You can start with ICMP and ping. But if it is a remote host ICMP can be blocked by routers. Better use nmap program.

Comment: ' Then how can I check if a address is reachable or not?' - try to connect to it.  There is no good alernative.  If the necessary TCP timeouts cause a problem, use an async/overlapped design or multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

It times out after about a minute. You can reduce that by using non-blocking mode and `select()` for writeability, with your timeout, after doing the connect.